# How to place background-image on right side of content

Tags: css, background-image, sprite, css-position

I am having trouble getting a background image to appear to the right of some text.

See page http://bit.ly/1FR0Tw3

The "right arrow" background-image sprite needs to be on the right side of the word "Next".

The sprite for the previous link's image-background is fine. It's just the Next link that I can't figure out.

**Here's my CSS**

```
div#maincontentcontainer div#inner-page-content div.entry-content div.post-nav-previous {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/investorcom-2015/images/post-nav-arrows.png') no-repeat left top;
    background-position: 0 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
div#maincontentcontainer div#inner-page-content div.entry-content div.post-nav-next {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/investorcom-2015/images/post-nav-arrows.png') no-repeat right top;
    background-position: 0 -15px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you hiding your site behind an URL shortener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background-position: right -15px;
```

Like this?

Comment: selected this as answer because it came in first -- @FirebladeDan's answer works too

Answer (score 2):

```
background-position: 30px -15px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the word Next in another div and set the css for the new div to margin-left:20px

```
<div class="post-nav-next">
    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
      Next
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok @AndyLewis -- but I preferred to do it within my css stylesheet via control over the sprite

Comment: Ah yes of course you can add a new class to that containing div and put it into your css file. The other answers are better than mine anyway; less markup.

Comment: I appreciate your taking time to respond. I up-voted your suggestion for some points...thanks